# Does inconsistency imply incompleteness?

Tags: logic, incompleteness

I'm self-studying the book [Incompleteness and Computability](https://ic.openlogicproject.org/) but I'm having troubles understanding the relation between consistency and completeness.

I'm working with the following definitions:

- A theory $\Gamma$ is consistent when no $A$ exists such that $\Gamma \vdash A$ $\land$ $\Gamma \vdash \neg A$.
- A theory $\Gamma$ is complete when for each $A$ either $\Gamma \vdash A$ or $\Gamma \vdash \neg A$ (but not both)

Assuming these definitions are correct (please correct me if they are not!), is it correct to say that if the theory $\Gamma$ is inconsistent then it is also incomplete?

My reasoning is that if $\Gamma$ is inconsistent then both $\Gamma \vdash A$ and $\Gamma \vdash \neg A$ for some $A$; hence, $A$ is a counterexample for the completeness of $\Gamma$, and so $\Gamma$ is incomplete.

If this is correct, however, it would imply that the contrapositive "$\Gamma$ complete $\implies$ $\Gamma$ consistent" is true, which feels a bit unintuitive to me.

Is something wrong with my line of reasoning, or maybe with my definitions?

Comment: The parenthetical "but not both" in the definition of "complete" is crucial here. If you include it in that definition, then inconsistent theories are incomplete. But if you don't include it,  then inconsistent theories are complete. I think it's very bad practice to make parenthetical  remarks like this, whose inclusion or exclusion changes the meaning. Especially in definitions.

Comment: Inconsistency results OVER compliments - which means that your axiomatic system leads to two negating proofs. Complete means that every statement may be prooved in one way or another but there is never inconsistency.

Comment: An inconsistent system is complete because it can prove everything , in particular every true statement. Of course we usually assume that a system is consistent and then ask whether it is complete.

Comment: That the system can prove not only $A$ , but also not $A$ does not make it incomplete. That it must be impossible to prove both is the aspect of the consistency , not of the completeness.

Comment: @Peter so I should take the "either...or..." in the Completeness definition as an inclusive OR instead of and exclusive OR, right? But that would be in contrast with e.g. [Wiki on Complete Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_theory), which explicitly says that, in a complete theory, "for every sentence $\phi$, the theory $\Gamma$ contains the sentence or its negation *but not both*".

Comment: This is surely because an inconsistent theory has no merit at all (not even a theoretical merit) because no proof within this theory allows any conclusion since everything (and its contrary) can be proven. So, usually we assume that a theory is consistent (because otherwise it is useless anyway) , and in this case , it can never prove both $A$ and "not $A$".

Comment: Amen to first comment by Andreas.  I've never seen Completeness defined this way (i.e. with the inclusion of 'but not both'). Is this your definition, or does this come from the book?

Comment: @Bram28 in the book (page 10) the expression "either...or..." is used, which I interpreted as an _exclusive_ or (though I'm not a native speaker, I may be wrong here). The parenthetical "but not both" is my addition, but I think it preserves the original meaning, doesn't it?

Comment: The English use of 'either ...or ...' typically expresses an XOR, yes, ... but not always. Consider: "I want to be either rich or happy". This is a perfectly good English expression you might encounter, but clearly the speaker isn't going to complain when they turn out to be rich *and* happy!  And I would say in this case, the book isn't using the 'either ... or ..' in an exclusive way either. Indeed, the standard definition of completeness is using the inclusive or: you want to be able to prove at least one of $\phi$ or $\neg \phi$. If you make it exclusive, you're getting ino consistency.

Comment: I would say something stronger than @Bram28 about "either ... or ..." in **mathematical** English: I would always read it as meaning the inclusive "or" unless the author explicitly says otherwise. And I would advise anyone writing mathematical English always to say explicitly when an exclusive "or" is intended.